# How to fix 405 (Method Not Allowed) using vue js and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi developers I have currently problem this project is an old project where the developer created. right now, we need to adjust some of there functionality. Right now I already extract the files to my localhost folder and now work without error on run watch and artisan serve. So the problem here is on login on the console it shows that http://localhost:8000/project/oauth/token 405 (Method Not Allowed), I really don't understand why this shows on the localhost however on the live server it works.

This project created using Vue Js and Laravel for the backend.
I will show you guys the authentication function.

Login Function:

```
authenticate(){
            this.login_alert = false
            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result)=>{
                if(result){
                    const self = this;
                    
                    const authUser = {}
                    try{
                        const data = {
                            username: this.email,
                            password: this.password,
                            remember: this.remember_me,
                            client_id: '2',
                            client_secret: 'secret',
                            grant_type : 'password',
                            scope : ''
                        }
                        this.$store.dispatch('AUTH_REQUEST',data)
                            .then(response=>{
                                console.log(data);
                                authUser.access_token = response.access_token
                                authUser.refresh_token = response.refresh_token
                                authUser.expires_in = response.expires_in
                                window.localStorage.setItem('project_token',JSON.stringify(authUser))

                                /*LOGIN*/
                                this.login_alert = false
                                this.loading = false

                                window.location.reload()
                            })
                            .catch(error=>{
                                this.login_alert = true
                                window.localStorage.removeItem('project_token')
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    }catch(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            })
        
        }
```

For the AUTH REQUEST:

```
AUTH_REQUEST:({commit,dispatch},obj)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        axios({
                url: '/project/oauth/token',
                data: obj,
                method:'post',
                config:'JSON'
            })
            .then(response=>{
                if(response.status == 200){
                    resolve(response.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                reject(error);
                localStorage.removeItem('project_token');
                commit('AUTH_ERROR',error);
            })
    
    })
},
```

Hope some one experience this. thanks.

Comment: just run ```php artisan route:list``` and check if there is a route with url of /project/oauth/token

Comment: @TEFO hi tefo i tried that but there is an error ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\LoginController does not exist

Comment: remove Auth::routes(); temporary or wherever this route(s) are.

Comment: there is no auth::route() inside web.php and api.php

Comment: so remove or comment the route for this route. and can you share this AUTH_REQUEST how you request it in vuex?

Comment: i will update my content to share to you the auth_request function

Comment: @TEFO please see the updated content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218386/discussion-between-devge-and-tefo).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the compilation of the route should be specified properly, for example

```
async purchaseDelete(purchase) {
        Csrf.getCookie();
        return Api.delete('/api/purchase_settings/${purchase.id}');
    },
```

the single tick on the axios delete method didnt represent correctly

```
async purchaseDelete(purchase) {
    Csrf.getCookie();
    return Api.delete(`/api/purchase_settings/${purchase.id}`);
}
```

When changed to back ticks, it responded with the correct result